# $f(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible over $F$ if $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ implies that $g(x) \in F$ or $h(x) \in F$ where $F$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> $f(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible over $F$ if $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ implies that $g(x) \in F$ or $h(x) \in F$ where $F$ is a field.

If $g(x) \in F$ or $h(x) \in F$, then doesn't that make $f(x)$ reducible since it has factors in $F$?

Comment: If that was the case, every polynomial in $F[x]$ would be reducible since $f=1\cdot f$.

Answer (score 0):

No, because being reducible (if $f(x)\ne0$) means that you can factor it as a product of *non-invertible* elements of $F[x]$.

Comment: This is just a comment (which says quite a bit about the question, if you ask me).